# Reading Cassandra from Spark, getting "IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported data source V2 partitioning type: CassandraPartitioning"

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to read cassandra from spark but I m getting :

> Unsupported data source V2 partitioning type: CassandraPartitioning

spark : 3.3
scala : 2.12
cassandra connector : 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

V2 partitioning is completely new in Spark 3.3 introduced by [SPARK-37377](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37377).

At the time of writing, the latest version of Spark Cassandra connector (v3.2) only [works with Apache Spark 3.2](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility). The connector currently does not support Spark 3.3. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

maximum spark version supported by the cassandra connector is 3.2.2